# Laravel IronMQ class not found exception

Tags: laravel, queue

I am trying to push new queue using **iron.io** and Laravel **queues**.
Upon deploy I got this message:

```
Class 'IronMQ' not found
```

But,there is no class with that name - there is **IronMQ_Message** class in **iron.io** package. That package is very simple, and it is not so hard to take a peak inside, but I wonder am I missing something ? Maybe some recent fixes, because I am using it for the first time ? Anybody had that issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add

```
"iron-io/iron_mq": "dev-master"
```

To your composer.json.

Then delete your `vendor` folder, your `composer.lock` and

```
composer install
```

Again. Sometimes we get those errors with Iron.

Comment: This may also be because of recent changes the library "If you're using laravel and see "Class IronMQ not found" error set iron_mq version to 1.* and install dependencies" - https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php